# Importing .DAT file with no delimiters

Tags: r, delimiter

I was supposed to use CSPro for my coding project, but then it is unavailable in MacOS. So I opted for R. However, I'm now having a problem importing .dat files with no delimiters. Here's a snippet:

```
2 12802033000000600300001000102800211000004000100203300002031251634 2                         51 ACCOUNTANT-AUDITING      2411AUDITING PRIVATE COMPANY 692010804822214008332 048                                         1ACCOUNTANT               69201 20005818078
```

I have the dcf file, corresponding to the .dat file and found out that the lens were differing across columns.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't help you unless you gives us some metadata - data about data.  What columns do you expect to find on each line of your .dat file?  What format and length do you expect each to take?  Welcome to SO.

Comment: do you not have access to the csdb file? that would allow you to access the data directly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).